# Oracle SQL with Join and count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

I would like to join two tables, A and B, with a count function.

Table A has the followings:

```
SQL> select a.book_id, count(a.book_id)
   from
   a 
   group by a.book_id ; 

BOOK_ID COUNT(A.BOOK_ID)
--------- ----------------
    1                2
    2                2
    3                2
    4                2
    5                2
    6                3
```

and table B has the followings:

```
 SQL> select b.book_id, count(b.book_id)
from
b 
group by b.book_id ; 

 BOOK_ID COUNT(B.BOOK_ID)
--------- ----------------
     6                2
```

So I would like to have a query which gives me the following result:

```
 BOOK_ID COUNT(A.BOOK_ID)    COUNT(B.BOOK_ID)
--------- ----------------   ----------------
    1                2                   0
    2                2                   0
    3                2                   0
    4                2                   0
    5                2                   0
    6                3                   2
```

I tried this :

```
  SQL> select b.book_id, count(b.book_id),a.book_id, count(a.book_id)
  from
  b , a 
  where
  b.book_id(+) = a.book_id
 group by b.book_id, a.book_id ;
```

but the results were like this :

```
   BOOK_ID COUNT(B.BOOK_ID)   BOOK_ID COUNT(A.BOOK_ID)
 --------- ---------------- --------- ----------------
                     0         1                2
                     0         2                2
                     0         3                2
                     0         4                2
                     0         5                2
    6                6         6                6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
select  a.book_id as id_a,  
        (select count(1) from a a2 where a2.book_id = a.book_id) as count_a,
        b.book_id as id_b,
        (select count(1) from b b2 where b2.book_id = a.book_id) as count_b
from a
left join b on b.book_id  = a.book_id
group by a.book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
WITH total_list AS (
    SELECT a.Book_id, 'a' AS a_cnt, NULL AS b_cnt FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.Book_id, NULL, 'b')
SELECT Book_id, COUNT(a_cnt) AS a_total, COUNT(b_cnt) AS b_total
GROUP BY Book_id
ORDER BY Book_id
```

What this does is it uses a subquery to union together both of your book tables and attaches a flag to it to signify if it belonged to table a or table b. From there, I just selected from the subquery.